# iOS - Wrong label color on some iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, colors, uilabel

I have a label that should be white. On some iPhones though it is black and I have no idea why. I'm not changing the color in code, it is set in IB, and I don't even see any consistency in this bug because let's say on one i6 it is white on the other i6 it is black. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using UIColor.WhiteColor or #FFFFFF ?

Comment: In the IB from the preset colors I selected "White".

Comment: Please try to set it by code. And check.

Comment: OK, this solves it but I'm still curious why did this happen